# how to execute a python program in a shell script

Tags: shell, ubuntu, shell-script, scripting

I have a python program in that I wrote some python code (disk.py). I executed this program using the command `python disk.py` in a terminal, it worked.

Now I want to execute it using a shell script.

Comment: You mean executing like `./disk.py` (wild guess)? If so, you just need to add a suitable hash-bang, i.e. `#!/usr/bin/python`. If you mean some else, you need to clarify what you are talking about.

Comment: First, rewrite the program logic in Shell script. Or I'm confused!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To be able to execute as `./disk.py` you need two things:

1. Change the first line to this: `#!/usr/bin/env python`
2. Make the script executable: `chmod +x disk.py`

Comment: why we need to write like this #/usr/bin/env python. what's purpose for env python

Comment: @rajcoumar it's more portable this way. In some systems python might be in `/usr/bin/python`, in others it might be `/opt/bin/python`. With `#!/usr/bin/env python` it should work in all systems where python is correctly installed, regardless of its exact location.

Comment: Isn't it python script rather than `shell script` ?

Answer (score 25):

Shell script should be like:

```
#!/bin/sh
python disk.py
```

Comment: This answer actually addresses the Original Question better, because the latter clearly says "execute python program **in a** shell script"

Answer (score 6):

As @SHW mentioned, the question actually asks about executing a python program **in a** shell script (not running the python script directly with `./disk.py`)

So, expanding on @SHW answer, your shell script should be like:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/python /absolute/path/to/your/disk.py
```

Notice the `/usr/bin/python` instead of just `python`; using absolute paths helps the script to know exactly what python to use (to find the absolute path to your installed python use `which python`).

Same story when using absolute paths with your python script instead of just `disk.py`. In my case, I was trying to run a Django app from my bash script, so I had to add the absolute path of my `manage.py` for it to run correctly.

Also, regarding the header of your bash script, there are several alternatives to `#!/bin/bash`. Please, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376206/what-is-the-preferred-bash-shebang) question to know more about it.

Cheers.

Comment: +1 for answering the actual question.  ALSO thanks for including the python path. That solved the problem I was having!